# how to import scss files from html template to rails application correctly?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Using following - Rails 5.1.6 & Bootstrap 4

I trying to implement rails application with the help of html templete([Clean Blog](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/))

I tested bootstrap 4, its correctly installed and working. 
Now I have created custom.css.scss file in assets/stylesheets/ directory

```css
@import "bootstrap";

//partial scss files
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "global";
@import "navbar";
@import "masthead";
@import "post";
@import "contact";
@import "footer";
@import "bootstrap-overrides";
```

but getting error while running app
[image]

```css
// Bootstrap overrides for this template
.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  @include sans-serif-font;
}
```

Some scss files using variables and mixins. It need to be imported in each file just like below. How to make it right way?

```css
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

// Bootstrap overrides for this template
.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  @include sans-serif-font;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, simply adding a fonts directory isn't picked up by the pipeline. For now, let's just add that in there and then fix the Rails issue next.

```
|-app/
   |---assets/
       |-----fonts/
       |-----images/
```

The fix is pretty simple. Open your project's config file, located at `config/application.rb` and add the following line within your Application class:

```
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Above instructions not need if already font included anyhow

** Update Fonts path in your Sass**

Then update like this

```
// Bootstrap overrides for this template
.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 0;
   //@include sans-serif-font;
    font-family: 'sans-serif-font';
}
```

See the [`Using @font-face With Ruby on Rails`](http://vladigleba.com/blog/2013/11/29/using-at-font-face-with-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: i used gem it worked for font-awesome. Now I have to import variable scss file to each partial scss files to gain access of variable. Same goes to mixins partial scss. Its not look clean how to make it right?